# Is vectorization profitable in this case?

Tags: c, vectorization, sse

I broke a kernel down to several loops, in order to vectorize each one of them afterwards. One of this loops looks like:

```
int *array1; //Its size is "size+1";
int *array2; //Its size is "size+1";

//All positions of array1 and array2 are set to 0 here;

int *sArray1 = array1+1; //Shift one position so I start writing on pos 1
int *sArray2 = array2+1; //Shift one position so I start writing on pos 1

int bb = 0;

for(int i=0; i<size; i++){

   if(A[i] + bb > B[i]){
      bb = 1;
      sArray1[i] = S;
      sArray2[i] = 1;
   }
   else
      bb = 0;

}
```

Please note the loop-carried dependency, in `bb` - each comparison depends upon `bb`'s value, which is modified on the previous iteration.

What I thought about:

- I can be absolutely certain of some cases. For example, when `A[i]` is already greater than `B[i]`, I do not need to know what value `bb` carries from the previous iteration;
- When `A[i]` equals `B[i]`, I need to know what value `bb` carries from the previous iteration. However, I also need to account for the case when this happens in two consecutive positions; When I started to shape up these cases, it seemed that these becomes overly complicated and vectorization doesn't pay off.

Essentially, I'd like to know if this can be vectorized in an effective manner or if it is simply better to run this without any vectorization whatsoever.

Comment: it all depends on how large your `size` is and how much time this code takes in your application. if it contributes to less than 10% of total execution time, then I wouldn't even think about optimizing it, not even tunning it.

Comment: My question is if someone can come up with a vectorized solution that is faster than the code I posted, so you can assume I profiled the code and found out that this is a heavy kernel.

Comment: then are you sure it's computation-bound, not bandwidth-bound? are your sure SIMD can help?

Comment: My code is absolutely CPU-bound, there are very few accesses to memory, cache misses are very low, and I am sure that SSE would very much help here.

Comment: Does `int` have 32 bits? Does SSE work on 128 bits, working on 4 `int` items at once? (these are the defaults; other values are possible)

Comment: When you say "broke a kernel down to several loops", do you mean there used to be more work that could be done on the same data during this loop?  It's usually helpful to do as much as possible at once, rather than storing and then making another pass over the data.  Remember that with hyperthreading, two HW threads compete for the same L1/L2 cache.  Also, sometimes you can see optimizations due to data being in registers in various states of shuffling that wouldn't be possible if you broke a loop into multiple passes.

Answer (score 0):

You might not want to iterate over single elements, but have a loop over the chunks (where a chunk is defined by all elements within yielding the same `bb`).

The search for chunk boundraries could be vectorized (by hand using compiler specific SIMD intrinics probably).
And the action to be taken for single chunk of bb=1 could be vectorized, too.
The loop transformation is as follows:

```
size_t i_chunk_start = 0, i_chunk_end;
int bb_chunk = A[0] > B[0] ? 1 : 0;

while (i_chunk_start < isize) {
  if(bb_chunk) {
    /* find end of current chunk */
    for (i_chunk_end = i_chunk_start + 1; i_chunk_end < isize; ++i_chunk_end) {
      if(A[i_chunk_end] < B[i_chunk_end]) {
        break;
      }
    }
    /* process current chunk */
    for(size_t i = i_chunk_start; i < i_chunk_end; ++i) {
      sArray1[i] = S;
      sArray2[i] = 1;
    }
    bb_chunk = 0;
  } else {
    /* find end of current chunk */
    for (i_chunk_end = i_chunk_start + 1; i_chunk_end < isize; ++i_chunk_end) {
      if(A[i_chunk_end] > B[i_chunk_end]) {
        break;
      }
    }
    bb_chunk = 1;
  }

  /* prepare for next chunk */
  i_chunk_start = i_chunk_end;
 }
```

Now, each of the inner loops (all for loops) could potentially get vectorized.

Whether or not vectorization in this manner is superior to non-vectorization depends on whether the chunks have sufficient length in average.  You will only find out by benchmarking.

Comment: I think that you're ignoring the dependency the code has, and the problems it brings in terms of vectorization. Please provide code.

Comment: Here you go. Note how the loop carried dependency has bee moved into the outer loop.

Comment: This has possibilities.  If there are runs of many elements where `bb` doesn't flip, it's possible to quickly find them with SSE vector compare instructions.  (and writing `sArray1/2` for those positions is trivial.)  If `bb` changes a lot, you'll be stuck with more badly-predicted branches, and be in the scalar cleanup code a lot of the time.

Answer (score 0):

The effect of your loop body depends on two conditions:

- `A[i] > B[i]`
- `A[i] + 1 > B[i]`

Their calculation can be vectorized easily. Assuming `int` has 32 bits, and vectorized instructions work on 4 `int` values at a time, there are 8 bits per vectorized iteration (4 bits for each condition).

You can harvest those bits from a SSE register by [`_mm_movemask_epi8`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s090c8fk(v=vs.90).aspx). It's a bit inconvenient that it works on bytes and not on `int`s, but you can take care of it by a suitable shuffle.

Afterwards, use the 8 bits as an address to a LUT (of 256 entries), which stores 4-bit masks. These masks can be used to store the elements into destination conditionally, using `_mm_maskmoveu_si128`.

I am not sure such a complicated program is worthwhile - it involves much bit-fiddling for just x4 improvement in speed. Maybe it's better to build the masks by examining the decision bits individually. But vectorizing your comparisons and stores seems worthwhile in any case.

Comment: Use `_mm_movemask_ps` to take the high bit of every 32bit element.  Don't use `maskmove`: it automatically has a non-temporal hint (i.e. bypasses cache), which makes it horrible if you're going to read the data again soon.  Probably just AND or variable-blend to combine the old value of the dest with the elements that match the conditions.